# Change the shape of numpy array

Tags: word-embeddings, numpy, python-3.x, one-hot-encoding

My numpy array has the shape of (99,2) basically it has 2 columns one is the word and the other is a hot encoding vector size of 300 I want to delete the column of words and want to have only encoding vectors

in order to delete I have to use the simple line of code

```
arr = np.delete(x, 0, axis=1)
```

it deletes the all words but gives me the shape of

(99,1)

How Can I have the shape of (99,300)

Comment: That depends on the format of the data in your array. Could you provide details on what one element of your data looks like?

Comment: Thank you for the reply ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick I used is as below

First del that column by the following command

```
arr = np.delete(x, 0, axis=1)
```

Second Flatten the array ad make it a list

```
flt= arr.flatten()
flt =list(flt)
```

last make the new numpy array to restore the dimensions

```
new_arr = np.array(flt)
```

it gives me the desired shape